# 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a Springboot application as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/applicationContext.xml")
public class TaxBatchMain {

    @Autowired
    TaxIdService taxIdService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TaxBatchMain.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(TaxBatchMain.class).web(false).run(args);
        TaxBatchMain taxBatchMain = new TaxBatchMain();

    }

    public TaxBatchMain() {

        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void checkForTransactions() {

        try {
        ////
            String tab = "someother content";
        
            String footer  = taxIdService.formatFooter();
            ////
            ////
        } catch() {
        //////////
        
        }
    }
    
}
```

TaxIdServiceImpl class is as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class TaxIdServiceImpl implements TaxIdService {


    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    
     private String formatFooter(String footer) {
        String[] searchList = {"<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>", "<MS_ENV_NAME>"};
        String[] replacementList = {(String) servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContextKey.EMAIL_HOST_NAME.name()),
          (String) servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContextKey.MS_EMAIL_HOST_NAME.name())};

        return StringUtils.replaceEach(footer, searchList, replacementList);
    }

}
```

Application Context looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"....................///


<context:annotation-config />
    
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties" />

    <util:properties id="configProperties" location="classpath:/config.properties" />
    
  <!--   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:data/application.properties"/> -->
   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.main" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.mapper" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.util" />
    
    /////
```

When I run the main class I get foll. error

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field servletContext in com.tax.service.TaxIdServiceImpl required a bean of type `javax.servlet.ServletContext` that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `javax.servlet.ServletContext` in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling webEnvironment. It appears your [SpringApplicationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/api/) is not enabled with web environment.

`new SpringApplicationBuilder(TaxBatchMain.class).web(true).run(args);`

Since you are using spring-boot you can consider using Annotation based approach rather xml based.